# Blazor Validation | How to clear a custom error message

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, fluentvalidation

I'm new to Blazor and working on an EditFrom.

I have regular validation with FluentValidation and then I need to run a custom validation to make sure the email is not a duplicate.

That code is working good except, when I go to fix the email address and change it back to an email that I know is valid, the custom error message does not clear out on the `validationSummary` or the email field.

It appears the call for OnSubmit is not being fired even though all of the other validations are clear except the custom one.

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried everything from this post: [How to create Custom Data Annotation Validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413715/how-to-create-custom-data-annotation-validators)

Code:

Razor:

```
@page "/Identity/Account/ManageProfile"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Inputs
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Notifications
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider
@inject UserUtilities UserUtilities;
@attribute [Authorize]

<style>
    .control-container {
        width: 400px;
    }

    .btn-update {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .e-btn{
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
</style>


<EditForm Model="@Input" OnValidSubmit="@UpdateProfile">
    <FluentValidator TValidator="InputModelValidator" />
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <h2>Manage Profile</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <SfTextBox FloatLabelType="FloatLabelType.Auto" Placeholder="First Name" @bind-Value="Input.FirstName"></SfTextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <SfTextBox FloatLabelType="FloatLabelType.Auto" Placeholder="Last Name" @bind-Value="Input.LastName"></SfTextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <SfTextBox FloatLabelType="FloatLabelType.Auto" Placeholder="Email Address" @bind-Value="Input.Email"></SfTextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row btn-update">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <SfButton IsPrimary="true">Update</SfButton>
            <SfToast ID="toast_customDupemail" @ref="@toastDuplicateEmail" Title="Invalid Email" Content="@toastDupEmailErrorMsg" CssClass="e-toast-danger" Timeout=6000>
                <ToastPosition X="Center" Y="Top"></ToastPosition>
             </SfToast>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

CodeBehind:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using FluentValidation;
using Syncfusion.Blazor.Notifications;

namespace UI.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public partial class ManageProfile
    {
        public InputModel Input { get; set; } = new InputModel();
        private string toastDupEmailErrorMsg = string.Empty;
        private SfToast toastDuplicateEmail;

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() // = On Page Load
        {
            var userInfo = await UserUtilities.GetApplicationUser().ConfigureAwait(false);

            Input = new InputModel
            {
                FirstName = userInfo.FirstName,
                LastName = userInfo.LastName,
                Email = userInfo.Email
            };

            EditContext _editContext = new EditContext(Input);
            var _msgStore = new ValidationMessageStore(_editContext);
            //_editContext.OnValidationRequested += (s, e) => _msgStore.Clear();
            _editContext.OnFieldChanged += (s, e) => _msgStore.Clear(e.FieldIdentifier);
        }

        private async Task UpdateProfile(EditContext context)
        {
            //if (_editContext.Validate()) // <-- Model Validation
            //{
            //    if (await IsEmailValid(Input.Email).ConfigureAwait(false) == false)
            //    {
            //        await InvokeAsync(async () =>
            //        {
            //            var messages = new ValidationMessageStore(_editContext);
            //            messages.Clear();
            //            messages.Add(() => Input.Email, $"Username '{Input.Email}' is already taken.");
            //            _editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
            //            StateHasChanged();
            //        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
            //    }
            //}

            if (await IsEmailValid(Input.Email).ConfigureAwait(false) == false)
            {
                await InvokeAsync(async () =>
                {
                    var messages = new ValidationMessageStore(context);
                    messages.Clear();
                    messages.Add(() => Input.Email, $"Username '{Input.Email}' is already taken.");
                    context.EnableDataAnnotationsValidation();
                    context.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
                    StateHasChanged();
                }).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> IsEmailValid(string email)
        {
            var userInfo = await UserUtilities.GetApplicationUser().ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (string.Equals(userInfo.Email, email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }

            var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (user != null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(250)]
        [Display(Name = "First Name", Prompt = "Enter first name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(250)]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name", Prompt = "Enter last name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email", Prompt = "Enter email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class InputModelValidator : AbstractValidator<InputModel>
    {
        public InputModelValidator()
        {         
            RuleFor(e => e.FirstName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("First name is required.");
            RuleFor(e => e.LastName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Last name is required.");
            RuleFor(e => e.Email).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Email is required.");
            RuleFor(e => e.Email).EmailAddress().WithMessage("Email is not valid.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**

I've tried pretty much all of these suggestions: [How to reset custom validation errors when using editform in blazor razor page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60917323/how-to-reset-custom-validation-errors-when-using-editform-in-blazor-razor-page)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it with this [example](https://Create%20a%20custom%20form%20validator%20component%20for%20business%20logic%20validation). I created the `customFormValidator` and then put that within my `EditForm`

```
<EditForm Model="@Input" OnValidSubmit="@UpdateProfile">
    <FluentValidator TValidator="InputModelValidator" />
    <UI.Models.Other.CustomFormValidator @ref="@customFormValidator" />
```

Then in `UpdateProfile` I was able to clear it out.

Also, once I cleared out the email address that was now valid, the error cleared.

I assume that I was interacting the custom validation within FluentValidation and I needed a stand alone validator.

```
        private async Task UpdateProfile(EditContext context)
        {
            customFormValidator.ClearFormErrors();

            if (await IsEmailValid(Input.Email).ConfigureAwait(false) == false)
                var errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

                errors.Add("Email", new List<string>
                {
                    $"Username '{Input.Email}' is already taken."
                });

                await InvokeAsync(async () =>
                {
                    customFormValidator.DisplayFormErrors(errors);
                    StateHasChanged();
                }).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
```